# should Inter dependent microservices replicate data of dependent service

Tags: design-patterns, service, architecture, microservices, grpc

We have N microservices where N can be greater that 10. These N microservices depend on a Master Microservice M. So improving latency in our system we replicate bounded context information in each microservice 1 - N. I want to know more about it from external point of view, are we on right track or there is another way to handle such communication between microservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, there are N microservices each of which depends on some shared context. To improve performance, each of the microservices cache a view of the context locally.

Whether replication is the correct approach depends on the specifics of the shared context. The benefits of local caching in a distributed system are loosely based to the following:

1. What are the characteristics of the context?
2. Is it acceptable for a stale view of the context to be used for a short time?
3. How often does the context need to be accessed?
4. What is the likelihood that a given local cache access will succeed?

In my opinion, it is worth caching locally if:

1. The context is not updated frequently.
2. Using a stale view is acceptable for a short time.
3. M can't handle the volume of reads from N or N can't afford the cost of reads from M.
4. There is a high likelihood of finding a given context in the local cache.

In certain setups, network calls can be relatively fast and handling the possibility of a stale context and properly sizing local caches has its own set of issues. However, if N services need higher throughput or M is bottlenecked and the data is well suited to caching then local caching is a reasonable approach. Distributed caching services may be considered if there is a large amount of data to be cached or if you don't want to handle cache invalidations manually.